# Cannot create maven archetype: jpa-maven-archetype

Tags: maven, jpa, entities, maven-archetype

I'm trying to generate the archetype "jpa-maven-archetype" from console, but it only throws error messages about a non-existent archetype. I also consulted the list of the avaiable archetypes from mvn archetype:generate and it doesn't exists any more.

I was trying to auto-generate all entity classes for JPA from a database...do any of you knows about alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I doubt a Maven archetype would help you there anyway, archetypes are a bunch of predefined files and folders + Velocity templates. A software that can do it needs a database connection, a JDBC driver and advanced logic.

Tools like that exist, but are JPA-provider dependent, so it's down to what you use. See example references:

- [How to generate orm mapping classes from sql schema in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939667/how-to-generate-orm-mapping-classes-from-sql-schema-in-java),
- [Java, Code Generation, and Persistence Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764106/java-code-generation-and-persistence-frameworks)

Comment: MaDa, the thing is that I've found many posts about maven and jpa that makes me think this is possible. Actually, this archetype (jpa-maven-archetype) should do the job...but id doesn't...at least I can't find it!. thanks for answering so soon